# firefox-wget-window doesnt close after download

Tags: firefox, window, wget

I use Firefox with flashgot, which makes downloads via `wget`.
Some time ago, the wget-terminal-window appears, makes its download, and when finished correctly it disappears automatically.

Then there was an update... and now the wget-terminal-window does not disappear on its own. It waits for a keypress and then disappears.

`about:config` says, that when `wget` is invoked via `[URL] -c -T 15 -w 15` in a normal xterm, `wget` exits as ever when finished, even with these commandline options.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a wget issue, it's FlashGot. From their changelog:

```
[Unix] Turned the "Press any key to exit..." prompt
  (which was a lie) into "Press [ENTER] to quit..."
  The flashgot.term.autoClose about:config preference
  can be set to either to -1 (default) to prompt, 0
  to close the terminal immediately, or an integer
  number of seconds to wait before closing
```

https://flashgot.net/changelog

Comment: Can you [edit] in the link to their change log?